# Resetting a nickname

Tags: discord.py

Is it possible to reset a nickname of the target member. The case with the shown below is that when a member first joins he gets [] before his name. Then we use this to add something in the []. But when you want to replace the value inside the [] you get it like `[] <old.value> nickname`. Thus i need to reset it first when the command is used on members that already have some name in those [].

```py
    @command(name="nickname")
    async def nick_change(self, ctx, member: Member, nick) -> None:
        old_nick = member.nick.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")

        await member.edit(nick=f"[{nick}] {old_nick}")
        await ctx.send(f"{old_nick}'s corp set to {nick}")
```

Comment: Do you want to reset it to the default Discord-Tag?

Comment: Yes reset the name without it having the [] and the value inside them. But without it having the discord tag, only the name of the member as he would first join the guild.